# How to access the arithmetic value of count in \foreach, and use them in rotate box{}?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, count

I have a question about access the mathematical value of count in `\foreach`, I will used that value to do some calculation in the following code. But it didn't work.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle    45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-2.5,-3) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
% defining coordinates
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\coordinate (1)      at (0,2);
\coordinate (2)      at ($(origin)!1!120:(1)$);
\coordinate (3)      at ($(origin)!1!120:(2)$);
\coordinate (1_)     at ($(origin)!0.8!-5:(1)$);
\coordinate (2_)     at ($(origin)!0.8!-5:(2)$);
\coordinate (3_)     at ($(origin)!0.8!-5:(3)$);
\coordinate (_1)     at ($(origin)!0.8!5:(1)$);
\coordinate (_2)     at ($(origin)!0.8!5:(2)$);
\coordinate (_3)     at ($(origin)!0.8!5:(3)$);
% draw the circle
\draw [color=black, line width=0.5pt](origin) circle (2 cm);
%draw symmetry elements
\foreach \coordname in {1,2,3}
     \draw [line width=0.5pt, color=black] (\coordname)--     ($(origin)!1!180:(\coordname)$);
\foreach \coordname [count=\i] in {1,2,3}{
     \draw[color=black,font=\large] (\coordname)   node  {\rotatebox{120}{rota}};}
 \draw[color=black,font=\large] (origin)   node {rota};
 % draw plane group notaton
 \draw[color=black] (0,-2.5) node {$222$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

I need the text `rota` follow the direction of the curve of the circle depending on the position of the text.

Then I add some code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle    45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-2.5,-3) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
% defining coordinates
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\coordinate (1)      at (0,2);
\coordinate (2)      at ($(origin)!1!120:(1)$);
\coordinate (3)      at ($(origin)!1!120:(2)$);
\coordinate (1_)     at ($(origin)!0.8!-5:(1)$);
\coordinate (2_)     at ($(origin)!0.8!-5:(2)$);
\coordinate (3_)     at ($(origin)!0.8!-5:(3)$);
\coordinate (_1)     at ($(origin)!0.8!5:(1)$);
\coordinate (_2)     at ($(origin)!0.8!5:(2)$);
\coordinate (_3)     at ($(origin)!0.8!5:(3)$);
% draw the circle
\draw [color=black, line width=0.5pt](origin) circle (2 cm);
%draw symmetry elements
\foreach \coordname in {1,2,3}
     \draw [line width=0.5pt, color=black] (\coordname)--     ($(origin)!1!180:(\coordname)$);
\foreach \coordname [count=\i] in {1,2,3}{
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{\numbers[\i]};  % add
     \draw[color=black,font=\large] (\coordname)   node  {\rotatebox{-120+30*\n}{rota}};}    %some modification
 \draw[color=black,font=\large] (origin)   node {rota};
 % draw plane group notaton
 \draw[color=black] (0,-2.5) node {$222$};
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

It did not work.
Anyone has any ideas about what's wrong here? Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks :)  If it was just `\documentclass` and `\usepackage{tikz}`, it wouldn't be too much of an issue, but you're using additional Ti*k*Z libraries and you also have `\numbers` which is undefined.

Comment: where is `numbers` defined?

Comment: \number referred from other answers, I thought it is defined within the tikz package. Maybe this is the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, in your example, you have `\numbers[\i]` and I'm not entirely sure what it is referring to.  I removed parts of the code that weren't working and tried to see what you were looking for and here is what I have come up with:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}    
  \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);

  % draw the circle
  \draw [color=black, line width=0.5pt] (origin) circle (2 cm);

  % draw symmetry elements
  \foreach \coordname [count=\i] in {1,2,...,6} {
    \draw [rotate around={60*\i:(origin)}]
          (origin) -- +(2, 0)
          node [rotate=60*\i, pos=1, right] {rota};
    \coordinate (c\coordname) at ($(origin) + (60*\i:2)$);
  }

  \draw (c1) -- (c2) -- (c3) -- (c4) -- (c5) -- (c6) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the output:

[image: output]

I hope that is a helpful starting point for you.  Feel free to comment if you have any question as to how parts of this works.

Comment: X and y in tikz pictures is 1cm by default,  so I guess you can get rid of that :D

Comment: There's no need for `calc` and `arrows.meta` in this code. Also `x=1cm, y=1cm` are default values.

Comment: Oops, I used these libraries in the first iteration of this answer.  I left `x` and `y` just in case because he had it in originally.  EDIT: Actually, I've changed the code slightly so that it is all relative to `(origin)`.  So now I need the `calc` library again.

Answer (score 0):

I upload my solution to this question.

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{cry}{\hyphenchar\font=-1}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{cry}{m}{n}{ <-> cryst}{}
\newcommand{\cry}[1]{{\usefont{U}{cry}{m}{n} \symbol{#1}}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-2.5,-3) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
% defining coordinates
\coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
\coordinate (1)      at (0,2);
\coordinate (2)      at ($(origin)!1!120:(1)$);
\coordinate (3)      at ($(origin)!1!120:(2)$);
% draw the circle
\draw [color=black, line width=0.5pt](origin) circle (2 cm);
%draw symmetry elements
\foreach \coordname in {1,2,3}
    \draw [line width=0.5pt, color=black] (\coordname)-- ($(origin)!1!180:(\coordname)$);
\foreach \coordname [count=\i] in {1,2,3}{
    \draw[color=black,font=\large] (\coordname)  node [rotate=-210+120*\i] {\cry{2}};
    \draw[color=black,font=\large] ($(origin)!-1!(\coordname)$)  node [rotate=-210+120*\i] {\cry{2}};
}
\draw[color=black,font=\large] (origin)   node {\cry{3}};
% draw plane group notaton
\draw[color=black] (0,-2.5) node {$32$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]